# Такое выражение имеет право быть?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Помыв автобус руками местных
подростков, Габриэль определил меня на постой к своим друзьям.

Comment: О каком именно выражении идет речь?

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, грамматика здесь не нарушена. Действующее лицо здесь Габриель, что бы там ни говорили пуристы - и в деепричастии, и в глаголе.

А вот уместность самого приема "руками местных подростков" - это слишком субъективная вещь... Мне слух не режет.
(+)
Вот что мне не нравится, так это само сведение в некую причинно-следственную связь этих действий. Он что, не мог определить раньше, даже пока ему автобус мыли? Какая связь между этими событиями? ***Встретив меня с работы, моя жена оказалась беременная*** - что-то не то в такой конструкции при всей грамматической правильности.

Answer (score 1):

Да, имеет. Собственноручно поставив плюс ответу behemothus, заявляю, что деепричастные обороты могут отражать временную последовательность, а не только причинную связь.